# Hadoop resource manager jdk 8 dependency

Tags: java, hadoop

When I am trying to create a single cluster Hadoop environment, I cannot load the Node Manager or Resource Manager. From the log I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource 
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)  
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) 
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

... 83 more
```

I gather this is from a dependency on javax.activation from JDK8. The only online solution I could find involved changing these two lines in the yarn-env.sh file in the usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/{version}/libexec/etc/hadoop folder:

```
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"
```

`export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"`

This did not work and I continue to get the same error in the log when trying to run the YARN manager. Can anyone advise as to how to get around this dependency?

Environment:

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Apache Hadoop 2.10.0

Comment: Last I checked, Hadoop 2.x still requires Java 8. Why are you using 13?

Answer (score 0):

You can set JAVA_HOME variable in hadoop-env.sh to the location of a Java 8 installation, then it should start okay

Alternatively, use Docker or a pre-built quickstart VM such as those from Cloudera